# Python multiprocessing try to request GitHub api with two tokens in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, github-api

I'm trying to use function bucket() request GitHub API users' info with two access tokens in parallel. Then save users' info into a csv file. The reason why I'm doing this is to surpass GitHub API rate limit. Please ignore whether GitHub will block me or not. (I asked GitHub but got no reply yet.)
My approach is using Python multiprocessing library to run same function with different parameters in parallel. Actually, those two processes I created run sequentially, not in parallel. 
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import csv
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

# *************Construct url************
url1 = 'https://api.github.com/users'
url2 = 'https://api.github.com/users?since=1000000'
token1 = 'my_token1'
token2 = 'my_token2'
headers1 = {'Authorization': 'token %s' % token1}
headers2 = {'Authorization': 'token %s' % token2}
params = {'per_page': 100}

def bucket(url, header, params, file_path):
    count = 0
    cnt = 0
    csv_file = open(file_path, 'a', buffering=0)
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    while count < 1:    # just run 100 users' profile to see result fast
        r = requests.get(url, headers=header, params=params)  # get user's basic info, 100 users/request
        users = r.json()
        for user in users:
            user_profile = requests.get(user['url'], headers=header).json()  # get user's detailed profile, 1 user/request
            field_names = user_profile.keys()
            line = []
            for field in field_names:
                if (field in user_profile) and user_profile[field]:
                    if isinstance(user_profile[field], basestring):
                        line.append(user_profile[field].encode('utf-8'))
                    else:
                        line.append(user_profile[field])
                else:
                    line.append('NULL')
            writer.writerow(line)
            cnt += 1
            print cnt
            time.sleep(0.75)
        try:
            url = r.links['next'].get('url')   # get url for next page (100 users/page), 1 page is one request
        except:
            break
        print(r.headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining'])
        count += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=bucket(url3, headers3, params, 'GitHub_users3.csv'))
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=bucket(url4, headers4, params, 'GitHub_users4.csv'))
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

Could someone help me accomplish the goal? If you would like to share any idea that can pass GitHub api rate limit, I'm happy to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I asked GitHub but got no reply yet.

As I mentioned in the reply to your message -- using two tokens from the same user will not grant you a better rate limit because the rate limit for authenticated requests is per-user (not per-user per-token). And I'd strongly discourage you from creating multiple free accounts and using tokens from those as a way to work around the rate limit (since it's not allowed by the ToS).